# Saving a objects id to a nested has_many through model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relationship

I have 3 models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :project_files, through: :projects

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :project_files

class ProjectFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
```

When I create a `project_file` using something like:

```
@project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
@project.project_files.new
```

It doesn't save the users id to the project_file record, but it does save the projects id.

I want to be able to get access to it User by calling `@project_file.user` and it return the id

Comment: I think your syntax: `@project.project_file.new` is incorrect, are you sure that it's working? It should be: `@project.project_files.new` instead.

Comment: Apologies I wrote it out wrong in this example I have edited the code now. I do have `@project.project_files.new` in my code

Comment: Sorry, but `current_user.project.find(params[:id])` should also be: `current_user.projects.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Sorry yeah I have fixed that as well.

Comment: You don't seem to have any association in `ProjectFile ` for `User`, what are you exactly expecting?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to call `@project_file.user` and get its associated object back. I was going with this example http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association the second example (talks about document, section and paragraph) shows basically what I want.

Comment: Then @Chumakoff's answer looks fine to me? Unless you wanna explain what are you exactly looking for? You want an association or just a `user` method in `ProjectFile`?

Comment: I thought it would of been possible to just do project_file.user rather than having to find it's associated project as well.

Comment: Of course you'll have to find associated project first to get to user because that's how you have configured your associations. If you were to have `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :project` in `ProjectFile` then you could have setup `has_many through: ...` the way it's mentioned in guide. I think you'll have to create `user` method as suggested in the answer, unless you are looking for something else.

Comment: I have added the `belongs_to :user` in the ProjectFile model saved a record using 
`@project = current_user.projects.find(params[:project_id])`

`@project_file = @project.project_files.create`

And it is still not setting the `user_id` I thought because they are now all related rails would be smart enough to know that it should see the id and add it

Comment: Do you have `user_id` column in `ProjectFile` as well? Can you please post the db schema of all these models to look at?

Comment: here is a link to a gist https://gist.github.com/samjbmason/0492930b789be7135806

Comment: you should use `has_one :user, through: :project` in `ProjectFile`. Another thing `@project.project_files.build`.

Comment: so instead of `belongs_to :user` I should use the `has_one`? So `@project.project_files.build` should be used over `new` or `create`?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your [gist](https://gist.github.com/samjbmason/0492930b789be7135806), it seems that you've to change your associations a bit in order to make things work as you're expecting:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_files
  has_many :projects, through: :project_files

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_files
  has_many :users, through: :project_files

class ProjectFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
```

Also, there's no point of having `user_id` column for `Project` unless you're going to use it for some different purpose than just the association, I mean, you don't need it if `user_id` in projects and project_files are going to be the same. Well, now, you can do this with `current_user` using `project_files`:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id]) # project to be associated
@project_file = current_user.project_files.build(project: @project)
```

or:

```
@project_file = current_user.project_files.build(project_id: params[:id])
```

and then:

```
@project_file.save # save the association between user and project!
```

Your `user_id` in `project_files` should be saved and committed to db now. But, it will not save `user_id` in `projects` as there's really no point of having `user_id` in two different tables(unless you point out one in your comment/question).